# Using Ranking Functions for Sets of Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, ranking-functions

I have the following syntax which created the below table:

```
SELECT [OPEN_DATE]
      ,[CODE]
      ,[ID]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID],[CODE] ORDER BY [OPEN_DATE],[CODE]) AS [RowOrder]
FROM [Table]


OPEN_DATE   CODE    ID  RowOrder
6/8/2021    AA  11052   1
6/8/2021    AA  11052   2
6/8/2021    AA  11052   3
6/8/2021    AB  11052   1
6/8/2021    AB  11052   2
6/8/2021    AB  11052   3
7/15/2021   AC  89321   1
7/15/2021   AC  89321   2
7/15/2021   AC  89321   3
9/24/2022   AD  89321   1
9/24/2022   AD  89321   2
9/24/2022   AD  89321   3
```

I need to add column to number these in sets/groups like so:

```
OPEN_DATE   CODE    ID  RowOrder    SetOrder
6/8/2021    AA  11052   1           1
6/8/2021    AA  11052   2           1
6/8/2021    AA  11052   3           1
6/8/2021    AB  11052   1           2
6/8/2021    AB  11052   2           2
6/8/2021    AB  11052   3           2
7/15/2021   AC  89321   1           1
7/15/2021   AC  89321   2           1
7/15/2021   AC  89321   3           1
9/24/2022   AD  89321   1           2
9/24/2022   AD  89321   2           2
9/24/2022   AD  89321   3           2
```

Notice SetOrder increases by 1 when Code changes but ID stays the same, and then it resets to 1 when ID changes.

I tried using ROW_NUMBER again as well as DENSE_RANK and RANK, but none of them seem to work.  Is there another function I haven't thought of?

Thank you.

Comment: `PARTITION BY [ID],[CODE] ORDER BY [OPEN_DATE],[CODE]` is just the same as `PARTITION BY [ID],[CODE] ORDER BY [OPEN_DATE]` as within a `[OPEN_DATE],[CODE]` partition all the Codes are the same so the secondary sort by `CODE` never adds anything

Comment: So you have no deterministic ordering of rows within the same `OPEN_DATE` but this seems to be required to get your desired results

Comment: Is it possible for, say, Code = AA, ID = 11052, and an open_date other than 2021-06-08?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DENSE_RANK` for this

```sql
SELECT OPEN_DATE
      ,CODE
      ,ID
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, CODE ORDER BY OPEN_DATE) AS RowOrder
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CODE) AS SetOrder
FROM [Table]
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c1743a17992e48913a1ba42265a763a6)

Note that `CODE` in the `ORDER BY` of `RowOrder` makes no sense, as it's already in the `PARTITION BY`.